# Current limiting resistors and voltage dividers

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-divider, current-source, current-limiting

I was once told that current and voltage is like a water in a river, the speed of the water can be likened to the voltage and the current is the width of the river. However, my confusion is when it comes to current limiting and voltage dividers.

My understanding, and I may be wrong, is that if I put a 10 kΩ resistor in series on, say, a 5 V circuit, that the voltage will still be 5 V, but the current will be limited.

So how is it that if I use, say, a 2 kΩ/ 1 kΩ as a voltage divider, the voltage is around 3.3 V and is the current limited at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was once told that current and voltage is like a water in a river, the speed of the water can be likened to the voltage and the current is the width of the river.

Not quite. Voltage would be like water pressure - given by the height of the water tank above the outlet, say. A wide river might have no flow so that's not a good analogy. A better one is that electrical current (the flow of charge per unit time) is analagous to water current (the mass of water passing a point per unit time).

> My understanding and I may be wrong, is that if I put a 10k resistor in series on say a 5 V circuit, that the voltage will still be 5 V, but the current will be limited.

Yes and the relationship is given by Ohm's law, \$ V = IR \$, or, rearranged, \$ I = \frac V R \$.

Before you add the resistor you have infinite resistance so \$ I = \frac 5 {\infty} = 0\$.

After you add the 10 kΩ resistor \$ I = \frac 5 {10k} = 0.5 \text{mA} \$.

> So how is it that if I use say a 2k/1K as a voltage divider the voltage is around 3.3v and is the current limited at the same time?

A 2k/1k voltage divide has a total resistance of 3 kΩ so at 5 V the current flow will be \$ I = \frac 5 {3k} = 1.666 \text{mA} \$. The voltage drop across the 1k resistor will be \$ V = IR = 1.666m \times 1k = 1.666 \text V \$ and the remaining 3.333 V will be dropped across the 2 kΩ resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frjW96.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Simulation of 2/3 and 1/3 voltage dividers.*

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful.  I've been blindly following examples with my circuit design without really  knowing why it works.  It's good to know the reasoning behind things

Answer (score 3):

> I was once told that current and voltage is like a water in a river, the speed of the water can be likened to the voltage and the current is the width of the river.

That's plain confusing. Usually it is taught like:

- Current is analogous to a river's current, the flow of water. In fact it's the very reason it is called current.
- Resistance is analogous to the river's width.
- Voltage is analogous to how much water you have available upstreams before the river.

> if I put a 10k resistor in series on say a 5v circuit, that the voltage will still be 5v, but the current will be limited.

Yes, if you have 5 tons of water available upstreams (voltage), you'll still have those 5 tons of water no matter how broad or narrow the downstream river is (resistance). However, the flow of water (current) will greatly depend on how broad the river is.

But this isn't a great analogy beyond explaining electricity to complete novices. Because in the real world, water has a weight and there is gravity, and together they are forming water pressure... which isn't really analogous to electricity at all.

> So how is it that if I use say a 2k/1K as a voltage divider the voltage is around 3.3v and is the current limited at the same time?

The water analogy doesn't really translate well to voltage dividers, you would have to think of it as two rivers with a bassin in between them or something... it's probably just making things confusing.

The current is the same throughout the whole circuit, but it is regulated by both resistors and not just by the one with highest resistance.

Comment: tons of water upstream is also a confusing analogy. The water analogy translates to voltage dividers if you use pressure, or height, as is customary. If you have a thin section of pipe the water loses more pressure going through it, even if the section is short.

Answer (score 1):

### Analogies

> ... current and voltage is like a water in a river...

**General.** There are many examples in life where a *pressure-like quantity* (voltage) controls a *flow-like quantity* (current) through an *impedement-like quantity* (resistance).

**"Fish-tank".** This is maybe the best water analogy where the pump pressure controls the water flow by overcoming the valve obstructions in the pipeline.

[image: 'Fish-tank' analogy]

**"Communicating vessels".** This is another famous water analogy similar to your "river analogy". Here, the voltage is represented by a water column of proportional height. I have used this analogy in a stylized form (segments in red) to visualize the voltages in the pictures below;  currents are visualized by loops in green.

[image: Hydraulic analogy]

### Circuit evolution

> ... my confusion is when it comes to current limiting and voltage dividers.

These circuit configurations are closely related and exist together in circuits. I will show their evolution with a step-by-step scenario that I have used in my classes with students:

**1. "Ideal" voltage source.** Your 5 V voltage source is a typical example of such a device. Whatever load (resistance RL) you connect to it, its voltage will always be 5V.

[image: 'Ideal' voltage source]

**2. Real voltage source (unloaded).** Now connect a resistor Ri in series and an "ideal" voltmeter after the resistor. To our surprise, the voltmeter shows 5 V again. Why? The explanation is that although there is a resistance included in the circuit, there is no voltage drop across it because there is no current (open circuit). As a result, the voltage after Ri is the same as the voltage before Ri.

[image: Real voltage source (unloaded)]

**3. Real voltage source (loaded).** Now connect a load RL after Ri. The circuit is closed and current I = Vin/(Ri + RL) flows. There is a voltage drop across Ri and the output voltage across the load is decreased - VL = Vin.RL/(Ri + RL). In some cases this is undesirable...

[image: Real voltage source (loaded)]

**4. Voltage divider (unloaded).** ... but in others it is desirable because this is the way to reduce a voltage. Thus the voltage divider was invented where the total resistance Ri + RL determines the current and RL determines the output voltage. So *****the load resistance RL and the source resistance Ri constitute a voltage divider***** where *****the role of the second resistor RL is to cause a current to flow and a voltage drop to appear across Ri*****.

[image: Voltage divider (unloaded)]

**5. Voltage divider (loaded).** When the load has a high resistance and we still want to significantly reduce the voltage, we *****include an additional second resistor R2 in parallel to increase the current*****.

[image: Voltage divider (loaded)]

**6. Current-limiting resistor.** But if we go too far and connect a  load with a very low resistance (for example, in the case of a short-circuit RL = 0), the current will be determined only by Ri. This resistor then works as a "voltage-to-current converter" or, more simply, as a "current-limiting resistor". This is the simplest way to make a current source. I think this answers the OP's last question.

[image: Current-limiting resistor]

Answer (score -2):

That water-analogy is correct up to a certain extent.

Yes, the current is limited by the 2K resistor.

Answer (score -2):

Unless you have a certain voltage on the other side of 10K resistor, it is not a current limiter. The current will consumpted to the heat. [image]

As in the example of this circuit, you have to know that the color of LED in order to determine what voltage is needed to light that LED.

In shortly, you need a load on output of voltage devider and then you should decide which type of resistor or the value of resistor. Also you can look for npn BJT and "active current limiting circuits" for specific applications.

Comment: Could you try to make your point more clearly?